# PHP drop down list not generating

Tags: php

I need help regarding my PHP drop down list. I've created a Database call state. I'm trying to populate a state drop down on an html page using php connecting to mysql. Here is my code for the html page:

```
<form action="CreateUser.php" method="POST">
            <label type='text'>State:</label>
            <select name='state'>
            <option value='0'>--Choose a State--</option>
            <?php   
                    $dbTable='states'
                    $QueryResult=msql_query('Select * from       "$dbTable"'); 

                    while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult))
                    {
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $Row['StateID']; ?>">
                            <?php echo {$Row['StateName']}; ?>
                        </option>

            <?php   } ?>

            </select>


            <input id='movebutton' type = "Submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

And here is my PHP code for the dbconnection:

```
$DBName = "business"; 
$DBConnect = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if($DBConnect === FALSE)
{
    echo "<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "</p>"; 
}
else 
{       

    $DB = mysql_select_db($DBName, $DBConnect); 

    if(!$DB)
    {
        echo "<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "</p>";

        mysql_close($DBConnect); 
        $DBConnect = FALSE; 
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've checked on this forum and also on YouTube regarding PHP dropdown. I'm new to php and still learning.

Comment: are you sure you have put correct credentials and server information of db?

Answer (score 1):

The query is invalid.  It should be as follows:

```
$QueryResult=msql_query("Select * from `$dbTable`");
```

Comment: Yeah. `'` and `"` are not the same in PHP, that's where a big part of your problem lies :).

Answer (score 0):

Update your query like `$QueryResult=msql_query("Select * from '$dbTable'");` and also

Remove Curly braces inside option, or replace this code

```
<option value="<?php echo $Row['StateID']; ?>">
                            <?php echo $Row['StateName']; ?>
                        </option>
```